# What kind of weed is this taking over the yard?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

Can anyone identify this? It's starting to take over parts of my yard.

I'm in Chicago, if that helps.

Once we identify it, any recommendations to mitigate it?

[image]

Comment: I live close, in Ohio, but I can't make out the weed.  Can you take better and closer photos?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same weed in my lawn, but never really bothered to identify it beyond "it's probably a veronica of some kind". I think it's actually an annual that spreads solely by seed.

I have good news, "meh" news, and bad news - the good news is that once this plant sets seed in June, it either dies (if annual) or goes dormant (if perennial), the meh news is that it sets seed so it does spread, and the bad news is that if you have patches of lawn that thinned out over the winter, it may out-compete the grass that's there and make the patches worse.

I've tried Weed-B-Gone with no effect, although it's possible I applied it too late in the life cycle (plant had already set seed and was either dying or going dormant). I haven't had the chance to spray yet this year, but you could try spot-spraying now in hopes that it hasn't set seed. If you're successful on the timing, this should reduce infestation next year, when you can repeat the process and maybe completely eradicate it.

Another strategy is to increase the fullness of your lawngrass by following the correct fertilizer schedule for your area. In Wisconsin, that's fertilizing three times per year if you leave the clippings on the lawn and four if you don't. Plus, you can aerate it if compacted and dethatch if that's an issue. Anything to get the existing grass healthy and thick, which would prevent many of this thing's seeds from sprouting next spring.